# Automatic change value in database using ajax laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm newbie in ajax Laravel PHP. I'm working an appointment system with fullcalendar.io. I have three status, Confirmed "#1d8cf8", Cancelled "#fd5d93" and Reserved "#ff8d72". If the end date, is already finish, I wan't to change the value of "color" in database automatically to be "#00f2c3". It's means the appointment is already done.

This is my script:

```
$(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(".saveEvent").click(function () {

    let id = $("#modalCalendar input[name='id']").val();

    let title = $("#modalCalendar input[name='title']").val();

    let client_name = $("#modalCalendar input[name='client_name']").val();

    let email = $("#modalCalendar input[name='email']").val();

    let phone = $("#modalCalendar input[name='phone']").val();

    let note = $("#modalCalendar textarea[name='Note']").val();

    let package = $("#modalCalendar select[name='package']").val();

    let start = moment($("#modalCalendar input[name='start']").val(),"MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

    let end = moment($("#modalCalendar input[name='end']").val(),"MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

    let color = $("#modalCalendar select[name='color']").val();

     let Event = {

    title: title,
    client_name: client_name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    Note: note,
    start:start,
    end:end,
    package: package,
   color:color,


};
let route;

if(id == ''){
    route = routeEvents('routeEventStore');

}else{

    route = routeEvents('routeEventUpdate');
    Event.id = id;
    Event._method = 'PUT';

}

sendEvent(route,Event);


});
```

and this is my appointment controller:

```
public function loadEvents()
{


    $appointments = Appointment::all();
    return response()->json($appointments);
}

public function update(AppointmentRequest $request)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::where('id',$request->id)->first();
    $appointment->fill($request->all());
    $appointment->save();
    return response()->json(true);




}
public function store(AppointmentRequest $request)
{
    Appointment::create($request->all());

    return response()->json(true);
}
```

}

Do I need to make another function for that? I think I will use Carbon::now() for condition but I don't know how and where I will put the automatically expired code.

Comment: Hi, It seems you need a task scheduler which will run on some specified time, example every 30 mins or every 10 mins. Here is example tutorial, it might work for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7yQkQMp7Lw

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/